# How to fix a metallic bicycle basket to the back rack?

Tags: basket

I've been using plastic [cable connectors](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B000LR5DZE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), as can be seen in the picture below, to hold a bicycle basket fixed to the rack.

However, they loosen up every couple of months. What would be a better solution (easy to do, and more durable)?
[image]

Comment: Are the cable ties themselves failing? Because if so, simply using bigger/better ones would do the job.  Or is something slipping (in that case more cable ties)?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to arrange the cable ties the other way around. Put the locking mechanism under the rack, so it's not being bumped about by your cargo. That will also stop the ties damaging your cargo.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRicherby! and @Chris, I can see some cable ties end up only tied around the rack but not around the mesh, and other times they just loosen up. I think I will use bigger ones, and squeeze them tighter. Thanks again for your thoughts!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would look at 3~5 small aluminium fish plates in the basket, and small saddle clamps under the rails.  You'd need two small stainless steel bolts and nylock nuts per plate, or some other way to reduce vibration.

Suggesting Stainless Steel to avoid rust, or you could just use grease.  This will make undoing the bolts hard later, and rust may mark things you put in the basket, like cloth.

This suggestion would not be easier, but it will be a lot more durable.

There are metal zip ties, but they will have the same loosening problem, which is exacerbated by the small radius they have to clamp around.

Some ideas:

1. [image: https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/dda7169b-1a66-40fb-b4c3-1810b4b1be60/svn/national-hardware-u-bolts-2193bc-132-u-bolt-ss-64_1000.jpg]
2. Imagine the above but with the bow replaced by 
   [image: https://img2.exportersindia.com/product_images/bc-small/dir_69/2049675/u-clamp-594446.jpg]
   and some bolts with the threads facing downward.
3. You could use old spokes or other metal wire.  Spokes are hard to bent with fingers so pliers might be required.  Any sharp end could poke a hole into load items in the basket too.  I've got a box of thousands of galvanised concrete reinforcing tiedown wires that can be bent by hand.

[image: https://images.hdsupplysolutions.com/image/upload/d_no_image.gif,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_350,q_auto,w_350/119068_K_1_L.jpg]

Comment: The upshot here is that metal beats plastic for durability.

Comment: You could also use "worm drive" metal hose clamps, if you can find ones of the proper dimensions.  (They're hard to find thin enough and long enough for this service.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks yeah I thought about them - Jubilee clips, hose clamps, etc.  Downside is they require a certain minimum radius to work properly, and there just isn't enough width to clamp around here.

Answer (score 5):

I have a fair bit of experience with these baskets, and can tell you with confidence that the mesh will not hold up to any force that exceeds that of a plastic zip-tie. However, you might just want to try heavier-duty plastic zip ties with a metal pawl. Make sure  they are wrapped around the main frame of the basket, not just the mesh, and pull them as tight as you can. Also, if you insulate the contact points betwen the rack and the basket with a bit of rubber or leather (old inner tube works great), it will dampen a lot of the vibration that is probably causing the ties to come loose.

Answer (score 2):

I would either use some dedicated set, like this one: [Basil crate fixing set](https://www.basil.com/nl/crate-mounting-montage-set.html)
[image: Basil crate fixing set] (picture comes from their webpage).

Or I would fabricate something similar using 4 penny washers (on top of the basket) with 4 M4 or M5 bolts with nuts and 2 metal (aluminium) strips for under the carrier rack.

Perhaps 2 bolts with penny washers and 1 metal strip along the rack would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly improvise something using metal fasteners, you could also consider buying a **dedicated basket fastener**.

Ask your local bicycle store for a "basket fastener" or "basket holder" - they should be able to help you. The nice thing is that in addition to fasteners that are screwed in place, you can also get fasteners that can be detached by pressing a button  or lever - that is useful to detach the basket if you want to use it for shopping, or if you temporarily need the rack for something else.

I personally use the *KORBfix* (non-detachable) by Rixen & Kaul (German company, but also sold e.g. in the US) . For more information, go to the [manufacturer's site](https://www.klickfix.com/en/), and enter "korbfix" in the search box. Rixen & Kaul also offer a range of detachable fasteners, under the brand name *KLICKfix*.

Comment: Adding a single picture would make this answer better.

Comment: @Criggie: Unfortunately I don't have a picture handy, and using someone else's picture is legally dodgy, sorry.

Comment: Simply provide attribution to where a photo came from and you're fine.  Its not like you're claiming ownership of the image.  In this specific case, what if the linked site changes or closes?  Without that, we have no idea what the thing is you're describing, which renders the answer less useful in the long term.

Comment: @Criggie: "provide attribution to where a photo came from and you're fine" I sincerely hope you don't actually believe that.

Comment: @sleske To be more clear - your answer is lacking without a picture.   So take a photo of your clamp in-situ to help improve your answer.  Or draw a diagram in a drawing program.  Or sketch one on paper and photograph that.     At the moment its not got enough words to describe it clearly, hence the picture suggestion.

Comment: @Criggie: Sorry, I don't think I'll have time to take a picture and post it. Anyway, the gist of the answer is to ask / look for a dedicated fastener. The specific model is only for illustration purposes, and may not be suitable for OP. Anyway, if you have a suitable photo, feel free to edit.

Comment: I agree that the answer was also useful even without a picture (it's one google-images search away :) ). Thanks again.